# How to expand /boot whitout messing everything

Tags: partitioning, do-release-upgrade

i'm trying to update from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04, but I don't have free space available in /boot

[My partitioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQD8x.png)

So what I want is a way to expand /boot, or another way I can get free space in /boot (without warning my system), Is safe to move the Filesystem root to the right with Gparted?. Is safe deleting something in /boot?

[My /boot directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9VJH.png)

Comment: Is there a reason to even have a /boot partition (LVM, encryption, raid,...)? Without one, a directory in root (/) is used, and you have all the free space root has to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving partitions is never "safe".  The power could fail in the middle, or the disk could develop bad sectors while such a large amount of data is rewritten.

My usual approach to this is to steal some space from the swap partition to make a new boot partition, copy the old boot partition into the new one, update fstab (for both boot and swap) and unmount the old boot and mount the new boot, and then rerun update-grub.

If you are lucky enough for boot and swap to be adjacent, you might be able to delete swap, extend boot, and then recreate swap with the remainder.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude, I didn't know I can change the /boot location

Comment: There's a few cases on very old hardware where moving boot to the end of the disk is a problem, but that hasn't been an issue since before 64 bit cpus.  Also, for MBR boot has to be a primary partition, but you look to be using GPT anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To get you going, you can free up some space by truncating the unused initrd image. First, figure out your running kernel version by running

```
uname -a
```

If you're currently on 5.13.0-40, then truncate the old image

```
sudo -i
> /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-19-generic
```

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't work, because I need even more space, I only gave the partition 256mB, but I didn't know that, Thanks for the tip

Comment: This is actually a good approach if it can work at all.  Frequently the boot partition fills with stale images from previous releases that somehow don't get cleaned up and I've fixed it by pruning those many times.  However, if you are upgrading and out of /boot space, it's probably just too small.  256M was good once.  Now 500-800M is better, and I've been making them 1G to future proof them.